# Design Problem :: Creating a Guide to Incentives

Tags: information-graphics, information-design

*Background :: Many information design projects equip the viewer to act on the information presented. For that action to happen, the viewer must understand the behavior we want from them and be able to do it. The clearer we are with the goal and the path to follow, the more likely the viewer is to act the we want them to. I'd like to present a design problem along those lines that I'm working on right now.*

I'm seeking to create a 1-page guide or worksheet to assist renewable energy activists in developing community programs. The purpose of the guide is to communicate the different ways to incentivize adoption of renewable energy to different end users. My team and I want this guide to embody 2 concepts:

1. **Incentives ::** There are different sorts of incentives. For example, there are financial incentives like stipends and tax breaks. For another example, there are emotional incentives like feeling good about doing what you believe to be the right thing.
2. **Relationships ::** These incentives flow as transactions from one party to another. So a government might issue a tax break to a household, whereas a utility company might offer a stipend to a business, whereas a community leader might offer public recognition to a forward-looking utility company.

I have this drawing, which is intended to help activists ensure that any program they create delivers as many incentives as possible and at least one of each.

[image: Incentives Drawing]

However, I feel it does not make it clear (A) how they are supposed to use it and (B) for what purpose. How could I increase clarity of using this guide and clarity of its purpose?

You can read more about our project on [OpenIDEO.](https://openideo.com/challenge/renewable-energy/ideas/incentives-reference-guide)

*Note :: The best answer may or may not address my specific design challenge. They will address some principles of good information design for helping the viewer take a new action.*

Comment: Meta: My last question wasn't very good, and I was encouraged to frame my questions as design problems. I've sought to follow that advice here. Please let me know how I'm doing. I value feedback. A lot.

Comment: Perhaps it's me, but I don't really understand what's being asked here. Is that your final graphic? Are you asking about **design** or *organization of information*?

Comment: Thanks for your questions, @Scott. This is not my final graphic. I plan to render my final graphic in OmniGraffle.

Comment: @Scott you also asked, "Are you asking about design or organization of information?" Yes. I'm designing a piece of visual communication that includes a lot of information.

Comment: But are you asking how the **information show flow**, or what **appearance to use for the information**? To be perfectly frank, that sketch is so rough it would take 30 minutes to an hour to even understand it in order to provide any valuable input.

Comment: @Scott, I'm having a difficult time parsing the distinction you're making, but I'm sure you can help me understand. The things I'm wondering in my question above are, "Should they instructions (currently bottom-right) be moved to another position on the page?" "Would it be more effective if the relationship categories were on the right?" "How well is the angled line thing working?"

Comment: A fixed point is that I'd like to use a matrix as the basic structure.

Comment: Sorry I just don't understand what you are asking. It would seem to me as if you're seeking guidance on both design *and* organization -- Essentially asking for free design work.

Comment: @Scott, thanks for your candor. And sorry for not being clear. My own confusion is driving my lack of clarity. But it sounds like there's still hope for turning this muddy question into a clear and useful one. If you think there's hope, could you tell me if it be helpful if I edited my question to focus on either design *or* organization? If so, I'd pick **organization**. Are there any edits you'd recommend to focus my question on organization? On the other hand, if this question's dead in the water, let's close it.

Answer (score 0):

While I think the incentive section is clear, the relationship section isn't clear. I might even consider splitting relationship to "You are a" and "Your Target Market is". or something like that. Also instead of incentives, maybe use "benifits" or "selling points"

Overall though, I find that the purpose or goal of this isn't well communicated (that should also appear, preferably above the table)

Comment: Thanks for your critique! I'm going to go back to my team to work on clarifying the purpose.

Comment: I'd like to clarify the purpose as asking for input on organizing the information I'm trying to present. Are there any changes you'd recommend me making to the question to clarify its purpose?